# Iterate every combination of two elements in HashSet

Tags: c#, .net, linq, hashset

How could I iterate through each combination of two elements in a HashSet once?

```
foreach (var elt1 in hashSet) {
  foreach (var elt2 in hashSet) {
    ...
  }
}
```

This would iterate the combinations of two but would iterate each combination TWICE. I'd like to do it once.

I think it's easy to do in Python. Is there any way to do it in C#?

Sample:

input hashSet: { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

iterate through: (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4)

Comment: ToArray() the hashSet and then use the nested loops on the array?

Comment: This can be done, yes. Is there any neater way?

Comment: if hashSet contains n items, there shall be n * n combinations; the easiest way to generate them is nested loops, INHO

Comment: Could you please elaborate it little bit more... means whats your input look like and what will be the output and in between what do you want to perform, so that we have better picture of entire thing

Comment: @yper on top of my head, I don't think so. Just `ToArray()`, `For i 0 → size`, `For j i → size`

Comment: @yper what's not neat about Medinoc's solution?

Comment: @Eldritch Conundrum: I think the readability is not the best. I like MakeAllPairs() by dasblinkenlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in method to do this in C#. Since `HashSet<T>` is not indexed <sup>*</sup>, you cannot do it with two loops either.

If this is a one-time deal, the simplest solution is to make two nested loops on the results of `ToList()` or `ToArray()`, like this:

```
var items = hashSet.ToList();
for (var i = 0 ; i != items.Count ; i++) {
    var a = items[i];
    for (var j = i+1 ; j != items.Count ; j++) {
        var b = items[i];
    }
}
```

If you are looking for something reusable, make an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` that produces all pairs:

```
static IEnumerable<Tuple<T,T>> MakeAllPairs<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data) {
    var items = data.ToList();
    for (var i = 0 ; i != items.Count ; i++) {
        var a = items[i];
        for (var j = i+1 ; j != items.Count ; j++) {
            var b = items[i];
            yield return Tuple.Create(a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can iterate your pairs in a single loop:

```
foreach (var pair in hashSet.MakeAllPairs()) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", pair.Item1, pair.Item2);
}
```

<sup>*</sup> Technically, you could use `ElementAt<T>(int)` extension from `Enumerable`, but that would be very slow on large sets.

Answer (score 2):

**I misread the question originally. This is a new answer**

This is what you want (if working index-based is an option). Explanation is below

```
string[] myArray = GetArray();

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length - 1; i++)
{
    var element1 = myArray[i];

    for(int j = i + 1; j < myArray.Length; j++)
    {
        var element2 = myArray[j];
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", element1, element2);
    }
}
```

Explanation: Assume the following array:

```
Apple, Banana, Coconut, Zucchini
```

When `i = 0` (Apple), `j` will be 1 (Banana), then 2 (Coconut), then 3 (Zucchini)

When `i = 1` (Banana), `j` will be 2 (Coconut), then 3 (Zucchini).

And so on...

Basically, you are making sure **element j is always ahead of element i**. This means you've effectively removed half of the possibilities (where j would be *before* i), which is what you wanted.

Note: if you want to use sets of equal elements (Apple + Apple), the second for loop needs to change to:

```
    for(int j = i; j < myArray.Length; j++) //notice j = i instead of i + 1
```

Comment: Each combination would mean not only neighbor elements.

Comment: I changed my answer. I misread it completely. This one is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

To return all permutations (viz `(1,2)` and `(2,1)`), you can cross join the set with itself using `SelectMany`:

```
 var hashSet = new HashSet<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
 foreach (var elt in hashSet.SelectMany(
                     x => hashSet.Select(y => new Tuple<int, int>(x, y))))
 {
    Debug.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", elt.Item1, elt.Item2);
 }
```

**Edit**: If you just want the unique combinations (viz `(1,2)` but not `(2,1)`) then just add a filter only larger values during the cross join:

```
 var hashSet = new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
 foreach (var elt in hashSet.SelectMany(
                     x => hashSet.Where(y => y >= x)
                                 .Select(y => new Tuple<int, int>(x, y))))
 {
    Debug.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", elt.Item1, elt.Item2);
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent the same combination happening twice, e.g. 1+4 and 4+1. Which is what OP wanted, if I understand correctly.

Comment: OP's original question loops twice, from element 0, thus giving all permutations.

Comment: Quote from OP: `...but would iterate each combination TWICE. I'd like to do it once.` Which means that the order of elements is not relevant, 1+4 equals 4+1 and should not be run for every permutation, only for the combination.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a C(n, 2) combination.

Comment: @Fung: I think so. Not sure about those notations anymore :)

Comment: Updated - for combinations as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with indexes directly on the HashSet. 
Try this:

```
int int1, int2;
HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>();
hs.Add(1);
hs.Add(2);
hs.Add(3);
for (int i = 0; i < hs.Count-1; i++) {
    int1 = hs.ElementAt<int>(i);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < hs.Count; j++)
    {
        int2 = hs.ElementAt<int>(j);
    }
}
```